# Render Radio Element in Zend Forms

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have defined a form using `Zend\Form`. In that, there is a radio button.

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'nationality_radio',
        'type' => 'Radio',
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'local' => 'Local',
                'expatriate' => 'Expatriate',
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Its value is not directly binded with database column. But it should populate correct value taken form DB and save user input back. (eg - if value of table column `nationality` is `local` it should select `local` in radio button)

When rendered it should display as..

[image]

On form load, it will a select option considering column `nationality`. It will contain value either `local` or `expatriate`

```
        <?php
        if ($candidate->nationality == 'local'){
            $local = 'checked';
        } else if ($candidate->nationality == 'local'){
            $expatriate = 'checked';
        }
        ?>
```

In plain HTML i can do it as below,

```
    <div class="profile_item list-group-item">
        <span class="item_title">Local: </span>
        <span class="item_content"><input type="radio" name="nationality" value="local" <?php echo $local ?>></span><br>
        <span class="item_title">Expatriate: </span>
        <span class="item_content"><input type="radio" name="nationality" value="expatriate" <?php echo $expatriate ?>></span>
    </div>
```

But since Zend form rendered using  `<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('nationality_radio')); ?>` I couldn't do it. It just displayed as below.

[image]

How can i achieve my requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set the value, within controller method:

```
$form = new YourFormClass();
//are you using fieldsets? let's say no...
//if accepted value for $candidate->nationality could be only 'local' and 'expatriate',
//check the scope with your defined value_options or use an if
$form->get('nationality_radio')->setValue($candidate->nationality);
```

On your view use `formRadio` helper:

```
<?php echo $this->formRadio($form->get('nationality_radio'),\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio::LABEL_PREPEND);?>
```

Check out documentation at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#radio

or check classes:

`\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio`

and

`\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox`

Accepted values for `$labelPosition` are:

```
const LABEL_APPEND  = 'append';
const LABEL_PREPEND = 'prepend';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
            if ($candidate->nationality == 'local'){
                $LocalChecked="checked";
            } 
           else {
                $expatriateChecked ="checked";
            }
     ?> 



<div class="profile_item list-group-item">
        <span class="item_title">Local: </span>
        <span class="item_content"><input type="radio" name="nationality" value="local" <?php echo $LocalChecked ?>></span><br>
        <span class="item_title">Expatriate: </span>
        <span class="item_content"><input type="radio" name="nationality" value="expatriate" <?php echo $expatriateChecked ?>></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, That's what I did. Is there anyway to do with Zend/Form ?

Comment: You can set the value for the form element nationality in the controller Like ->setValue($candidate->nationality); where $candidate->nationality will be the value that u get from the db

Comment: Yes, That can be done. But how to render it as i want ? Label of radio must be in-front as in screenshot.

Comment: @Rashil Will setValue work for a radio ? How can i make it checked ?